# Show that for $a,b\in G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$ we have that $b=ah$ for some $h \in H$ iff $bH =aH$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that for $a,b \in G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$ we have that $b=ah$ for some $h \in H$ iff $bH =aH$.

Suppose that $b=ah$. Pick $x \in bH$, then $x = bh'$ for some $h' \in H$. However $b =ah$ so $$x = bh'=ahh'$$ and since $hh' \in H$ we have that $x \in aH$. Conversely pick $y \in aH$, then $y=ah'$ for some $h' \in H$. As $b=ah$ we have that $a = bh^{-1}$ so $$y=ah' = bh^{-1}h'$$ but $H$ is a subgroup and so $h^{-1}, h \in H$ so $y \in bH$ which implies that $bH=aH$.

Now suppose that $bH=aH$, then $bh' = ah''$ for $h',h'' \in H$. So $b = ah''h'^{-1}$, but how can I get the wanted equality from here?

Comment: "but how can I get the wanted equality from here?" Just set $h:=h''h'^{-1}\in H$. Then $b=ah$.

Comment: Note that "($b=ah\iff bH=aH$) for some $h\in H$" is false. What you mean should instead be written "($b=ah$ for some $h\in H$) $\iff bH=aH$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, we have, for all $x,y\in H$,

$$xy^{-1}\in H.$$

Can you take it from  here?

Answer (score 0):

If $bH=aH$, then in particular $bH\subseteq aH$, namely: $\forall h' \in H, \exists h''\in H$ such that $bh'=ah''$; now, call $h$ some $h''$ corresponding to $h'=e$; thence, $b=ah$. On the other hand, if $b=ah$ for some $h\in H$, then:
\begin{alignat}{1}
bH &= \{bh', h'\in H\} \\
&= \{ahh', h'\in H\} \\
&= \{ah'', h''\in H\} \\
&= aH
\end{alignat}
where the last but one equality holds because the map $H\to H$, $h'\mapsto hh'$, is surjective for every $h\in H$ (this uses the assumption that $H$ is a group).